# QML: Drag items get clipped when dragged outside of a ScrollView

Tags: qt, qml, scrollview, drag, clipping

I have a ScrollView which contains several draggable rectangles.

When I drag an item outside of that ScrollView, I want it to remain visible, but it gets clipped at the edge of the ScrollView.

I tried playing around with the z values, but it has absolutely no effect. Any idea on what else I could try?

Comment: Maybe parent it to something outside the scroll view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the rectangles' parent to the parent of `ScrollView` when the rectangle been dragged.

And if you want the rectangle always stay out of ScrollView after drag, assign a new state after the mouse release instead of `when: dragMe.drag.active`.

```
Item{
    id: root
    width: 500
    height: 500
    ScrollView {
        width: 200
        height: 200

        Item{
            width: 500
            height: 500

            Rectangle{
                id: rect
                color: "red"
                width: 50
                height: 50
                MouseArea{
                    id: dragMe
                    drag.target: parent
                    anchors.fill: parent
                }
                states: State {
                    when: dragMe.drag.active
                    ParentChange { target: rect; parent: root }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```